# How to add to an already created StackLayout without multiple: Children.Add?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Is there a way I can add to an already created `StackLayout` without the need of calling multiple `Children.Add`?

Here is the code that's been created:

```
public class Test1
{
    public StackLayout contentStack;

    public PopupDialog()
    {
        contentStack = new StackLayout()
        {
            Spacing = 0,
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,

        };
        contentStack.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "Test1" });
        contentStack.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "Test2" });
        contentStack.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "Test3" });
};
```

**Note that for this question I don't want to add within the `{ }` of the new `Stacklayout() { }`**

Comment: Are you not using bindings to generate your layout? That's one option, or are you just talking about using what code you have but the most terse syntax?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) contentStack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = $"Test{i}" });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends:

If you already have a collection you can do something like

```
public class Test1
{
    List<Label> list = new List<Label>()
    {
        new Label() { Text = "Test1" },
        new Label() { Text = "Test2" },
        new Label() { Text = "Test3" },
    };

    public StackLayout contentStack;

    public PopupDialog()
    {
        contentStack = new StackLayout()
        {
            Spacing = 0,
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,

        };

        foreach(var item in list)
            contentStack.Children.Add(item);
};
```

Other than that, i do not believe you can...

Comment: There's also `AddRange` to save another line of code but that's assuming that `StackLayout.Children` implements `List<T>` and you can cast to it and that you want to take the risk that Xamarin never change the internal implementation of `Children` :D

Comment: Children implements IList<T>, which comes without AddRange

Comment: That's what I'm saying - children implements `IList<T>` which is an interface, the implementation behind that interface *could* be `List<T>` but it might not be - so the above *could* work assuming you want to test it to find out and take the risk that the underlying `IList<T>` implementation always stays as `List<T>` or a type that derives from `List<T>`... always fun to look at what you probably shouldn't do when determining if you want to save a single line of code... after all, 99% of developers are inherently lazy!

Answer (score 0):

I think that even when your answer can be replied with a traditional loop as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019658/17303176  many people will reach this question looking for a more MVVM solution like using BindableLayout:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-8.0

In Xaml:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding User.TopFollowers}"
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             ...>
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                   WidthRequest="44"
                   HeightRequest="44"
                   ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

In C#

```
DataTemplate imageTemplate = ...;
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(stackLayout, viewModel.User.TopFollowers);
BindableLayout.SetItemTemplate(stackLayout, imageTemplate);
```